# What name to use in activation of encrypted root partition?

Tags: boot, kubuntu, encryption, boot-repair, luks

I am trying to run the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool on a Kubuntu 16.04 system with an encrypted (LUKS) root partition. [This post](https://dev-notes.eu/2016/09/mount-and-transfer-data-from-an-encrypted-filesystem-in-ubuntu/) tells me to "activate the encrypted drive using the correct name". That name should be given by /etc/crypttab in the live system.

My /etc/crypttab in the live system has no entries. The live system is also Kubuntu 16.04.

**How can I identify/find the name I need?**

Comment: Crossposted to [Ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413040&p=13839237#post13839237). If I get an answer anywhere, I'll make it available everywhere.

Comment: @user68186 Yes, I have an entry there. That seems to be what I was looking for. If you make that an answer I'll upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How to identify the name originally assigned to LUKS partition?

### Identify your root partition in the broken system when booted to Live USB

We will assume the encrypted partition is `/dev/sdXY` where X is a letter and Y is a number.

### Decrypt the root partition so we can look inside

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdXY temp_name
```

First, you will be asked for your `sudo password`. Type the password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Next it will say:

```
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdXY:
```

Type the passphrase and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Neither the password nor the passphrase will show and the cursor will not move. This is normal. This will create `/dev/mapper/temp_name`

### Mount the decrypted partition and see whats inside

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/temp_dir
sudo mount /dev/mapper/temp_name /mnt/temp_dir
sudo cat /mnt/temp_dir/etc/crypttab
```

The last line should show you the contents of the `crypttab` file which should look like:

```
correct_name UUID=78base79-8463-4046-a2b1-3a36b14cf42d none luks,timeout=30
```

Write down the `correct_name` to continue with the tutorial.

### Undo all the steps

Type the following commands to return everything as they were before:

```
sudo umount /mnt/temp_dir            # Un-mounts /dev/mapper/temp_name
sudo rmdir /mnt/temp_dir             # Deletes the temp_dir
sudo cryptsetup luksClose temp_name  # Un-maps the LUKS partition from tem_name
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tested the commands. For me at least they work. Unfortunately, it seems I don't have enough rep to upvote.