# Activating LUKS encrypted external drive from a previous install

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, luks

I inadvertently reinstalled Ubuntu without considering an external drive I had secured with [luks](/questions/tagged/luks) encryption. Reading [ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119579/what-name-to-use-in-activation-of-encrypted-root-partition) I understand the way to activate a LUKS encrypted drive, and I know the pass phrase, but I do not have access to the original system, so there's no way to identify the name originally assigned to the drive. I can retrieve header info from the drive, but nothing else.

```bsh
$ sudo cryptsetup -v luksDump /dev/sda1
LUKS header information for /dev/sda1
Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    xts-plain64
Hash spec:      sha256
```

It is my opinion that I'm screwed, (isn't that why they call it encryption?) In the slim chance I am wrong I'm hoping someone will enlighten me.

Comment: The `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdXY temp_name` command works?

Comment: No. I tried that earlier. It couldn't read drive.

Comment: This external drive that you secured with luks. Is it a drive you created and encrypted yourself, using `luksFormat`, or was it created in some other way?

Comment: What I am missing are the [key slots](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318382/detemine-which-luks-slot-a-passphrase-is-in) from the `luksDump`. If the keys are not stored on the drive itself, your date is lost.

Comment: @Podesta The drive is one I added to system. I did encrypt it myself though I can't remember which online tutorial I used.

Comment: @Simon Sudler: If by, "keys", you are talking about something besides the pass phrase, then no. Keys were not stored on the drive.

Comment: Unless that is a very unorthodox tutorial you followed, like sharing the header across different drives and what not, a luks encrypted drive is completely independent. You can even decrypt and open them in Windows OS. The point of my original question is that if it was encrypted by the ubuntu installation, it would be using LVM. The problem that usually happens is that it chooses a default name for it, and if this name is shared with another drive, it can't read it, and you would have to change the lvname.

Comment: I'm sure it was luks format, but it's too late. I had to wipe the drive because I needed it. As this question is no longer relevant I will delete it unless someone objects.